# Scope: How to access/manipulate global variables in typescript

Tags: typescript, scope, ionic2

I am building an algorithm in typescript/ionic 2 that requires a function hierarchy (functions within functions). I am 99% sure that there is no way to avoid having nested functions because of the google API (long explanation required, just trust me on that)

I will use a simple demo that illustrates my problem to avoid posting 300 lines of code.

The problem involves accessing and manipulating global variables within the nested functions. I need a way of setting the this.secondvar in the secondSet function. Are there any ways to achieve this?

```
export class HomePage {

  public firstVar = [];
  public secondvar;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.setVar();
  }

  setVar(){
    this.firstVar.push("hello", "goodbye");
    console.log();
    getVar();

    function getVar(){
      //console.log(this.lol); unable to access
      secondSet();

      function secondSet(){
        console.log("test")
        //this.secondVar = "hello" //how do i set this ?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which takes the scope of the class.It will not have its own `this` value.

```
setVar(){
 this.firstVar.push("hello", "goodbye");
 console.log();

let getVar=()=>{
  //console.log(this.lol); unable to access

  let secondSet=()=>{
    console.log("test")
    //this.secondVar = "hello" //how do i set this ?
  }
        secondSet();

}
     getVar();
}
```

> what is the reasoning behind the positioning of the function calls? Why are they called after the function is declared?

It is because of the use of `let`.`let` variable declaration is [*block scoped*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html).
According to the docs:

> property of block-scoped variables is that they can’t be read or
>   written to before they’re actually declared. While these variables are
>   “present” throughout their scope, all points up until their
>   declaration are part of their temporal dead zone.

So:

```
     secondSet();//throws error

  let secondSet=()=>{
    console.log("test")
    //this.secondVar = "hello" //how do i set this ?
  }
```

Comment: "ts cannot find name "getVar""

Comment: Thanks. One question, what is the reasoning behind the positioning of the function calls? Why are they called after the function is declared?

Answer (score 1):

Use context variable. Assign value of "this" to a local variable say "context". use "context" variable as "this".

```
export class HomePage {

  public firstVar = [];
  public secondvar;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.setVar();
  }

  setVar(){
     var context = this;
    this.firstVar.push("hello", "goodbye");
    console.log();
    getVar();

    function getVar(){
      //console.log(this.lol); unable to access
      secondSet();

      function secondSet(){
        console.log("test")
        context.secondVar = "hello" // This is how you access the secondVar 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your inner functions to be arrow functions (lambdas), which will preserve the context of 'this'. So something like this:

```
var secondSet = () => { this.secondVar = 'whatever' };
```

If you look at the compiled javascript, it automatically saves the value of 'this' to a variable and uses that in the lambda.

Comment: How do i call that function

Comment: It's a function like any other so just secondSet(). Or any of the other ways you can call a function (call, apply).